# initialize a webdriver instance

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Hi i have a global class as belows:

```
public class Global 
{
    public WebDriver driver=null;
    public WebDriverWait wait=null;

    public Global()
    {
        BrowserInitializer obj=new BrowserInitializer();
        obj.initialize();
    }
}
```

I have another class called browser initializer where i want to initialize the driver instance to firefox as below:

```
public class BrowserInitializer extends Global 
{
    public void initialize()
    {
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
    }
}
```

I have testNG class where i want to run some test as belows :

```
public class TestNG1
{
Global globalObj=new Global();
    @Test
    public void login()
    {
        globalObj.driver.get("someURL");
        globalObj.driver.findElement(By.id("someid")).sendKeys("someusername");
        globalObj.driver.findElement(By.id("someid")).sendKeys("somepassword");
        globalObj.driver.findElement(By.id("someid")).submit();
    }
}
```

Now i am getting error like :

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class unitTest.myTest.TestNG1
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:38)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:110)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:186)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:160)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:141)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:271)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:577)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at unitTest.myTest.Global.<init>(Global.java:12)
    at unitTest.myTest.BrowserInitializer.<init>(BrowserInitializer.java:6)
    at unitTest.myTest.Global.<init>(Global.java:14)
```

but when i am initializing the driver instance in the constructor of the Global class i am able to run my test. what seems to be the problem? am i going wrong somewhere in the concepts of java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have infinite recursion when calling Global's constructor. Your `initialize()` is perfectly fine.

```
 public Global()
    {
        BrowserInitializer obj=new BrowserInitializer();
        obj.initialize();
    }
```

`BrowserInitializer` *is a* `Global`.

So `Global`'s contructor calls `BrowserInitializer`'s constructor (which calls `super`'s i.e  `Global`'s constructor again)

Use something like:

```
public class BrowserInitializer extends Global 
{
     BrowserInitializer(){
     super();
     this.initialize();
    }

    public void initialize()
    {
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
    }
}

//In test class
Global globalObj=new BrowserInitializer();
```

Comment: Is there any other way i do not want to expose my browser initialize class in test class. Also there are other methods too in the browser initialize class which are used by my other classes which are not exposed in the test class. so while calling them through the objects of browser initialize class unnecessarily the constructor will be called and it will try to again initialize the driver instance. Also in the constructor of global class there are other methods too which needs to be called to initialize some parameters globally one time. (This methods reside in non-test-exposable classes)

Comment: I'd recommend a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), _OR_ in case you don't want to modify your core code because of tests, you can use reflection. It should be acceptable for tests.

Comment: i have tried googling on factory and tried some dummy code but still the same issue. once i have initialized the driver instance in browser initialize code using factory method. then i am not able to hold on to that initialized value in other classes. the driver instance turns out to be null in my other classes which are extending global class and using the driver instance. why so? am i accessing them in some wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I woudl approach this in a different way, and use a @BeforeTes annotation;

Create a new webdriver class which extends Firefox driver;

```
public class MyFirefoxDriver extends FirefoxDriver {

    private WebDriverWait wait;

    private WebDriver driver;

    public MyFirefoxDriver()
    {
        super();
        this.manage().window().maximize();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(this, 5000);
    }

    public WebDriverWait getWebDriverWait() {
        return wait;
    }
}
```

Your test would then look like this;

```
public class TestNG1
{
    private MyFirefoxDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        driver = new MyFirefoxDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void login()
    {
        driver.get("someURL");
        driver.findElement(By.id("someid")).sendKeys("someusername");
        driver.findElement(By.id("someid")).sendKeys("somepassword");
        driver.findElement(By.id("someid")).submit();

        //To access the wait;
        WebDriverWait wait = driver.getWebDriverWait();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

I would be tempted to then further create a base test class;

```
public abstract class TestNGBase
{
    private MyFirefoxDriver driver;

    public MyFirefoxDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        driver = new MyFirefoxDriver();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

In which case you test would then look like this;

```
public class TestNG1 extends TestNGBase
{
    @Test
    public void login()
    {
        getDriver().get("someURL");
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("someid")).sendKeys("someusername");
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("someid")).sendKeys("somepassword");
        getDriver().findElement(By.id("someid")).submit();

        //To access the wait;
        WebDriverWait wait = getDriver().getWebDriverWait();
    }
}
```